# Javascript: How to write if a is a value from an array

Tags: javascript

var `a = [1,2,3,4];`

if given

> `b = 2`

how to verify b is in array a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely impossible.
Numbers are numbers, no matter what they came from; there is no association between a number (or any other object) and an array.

If you're trying to check whether the array has a `2` in it, call [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf).
For example:

```
if (a.indexOf(2) < 0)
    //Not Found! Waaah!
```

Note that `indexOf` does not exist in IE.
You can write it yourself, like this:  (courtesy of Mozilla)

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (len === 0)
      return -1;

    var n = 0;
    if (arguments.length > 0)
    {
      n = Number(arguments[1]);
      if (n !== n)
        n = 0;
      else if (n !== 0 && n !== (1 / 0) && n !== -(1 / 0))
        n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
    }

    if (n >= len)
      return -1;

    var k = n >= 0
          ? n
          : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    for (; k < len; k++)
    {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
        return k;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you give some code snippet? I'm trying to achieve the syntax in python str in "strstr"

Comment: I'd rather do `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) if(a[i] == 2) return i; return -1;`, it's less messy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to do:

```
var result = a[b];
if (typeof(result) !== "undefined") {

}
```

Comment: I think he wants to know if the value of b is in a, not if there's a value at the index b.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = 2;

if (~a.indexOf(b)) {
    alert('Yup, it is in here!');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that `indexOf` isn't implemented in IE, you can either loop through each item in `a` (recommended), or if you're after a one-liner (this is currently only designed for integers):

```
new RegExp("\\b" + b + "\\b").test(a.join(",")); // Will return true or false
```

Comment: one must accept that *sometimes* regular expressions just aren't fit for a job

Comment: @Ben why not? If you read my answer carefully you'll see that I recommend using a loop anyway, but hey, I'm all up for different ideas as long as they're not ridiculous. And in this case, I don't think a regex is ridiculous.

Comment: Just seems ridiculous to join an array of numbers into a string to run a regexp to see if one number is in that array...

Comment: @Ben - Each to their own. Personally, I prefer a bit of *creative* programmming ;)